# A box-constrained least-squares problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, least-squares, quadratic-programming

I need to solve the following problem in $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb R^p$.

$$\min_{\mathbf{s} \in [-1,1]^p}\left\Vert \mathbf{x}-\lambda\mathbf{s}\right\Vert _{2}$$

where $\mathbf{s} \in \mathbb R^p$ and $\lambda>0$ are given. I could not make any progress. How to solve this problem?

---

**EDIT**: It seems the problem is modified version of the problem 4.12 of the book [Statistical learning with sparsity.](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity/)

Comment: How about $\mathrm{x}=\lambda\alpha \mathrm{s}$?

Comment: I think the answer must contain soft thresholding operator. Something like $S\left(\mathbf{x},\lambda\alpha\right)$ because of sqrt($\ell_2$) norm, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the objective function to $\|\frac{x}{\lambda} - s\|_2$; the solution will be the same. Then you are just performing a projection of $x/\lambda$ onto the cube $[-1, 1]^p$, which is given by a "clipping" each component of $x/\lambda$ to the interval $[-1, 1]$.
$$s_i = \text{Proj}_{[-1, 1]} (x_i / \lambda) = \min\{\max\{x_i / \lambda, -1\}, 1\}$$